# Cant click hebrew text Selenium Web Driver Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently playing a bit with Selenium Web Driver using Python (Chrome driver),
and for some reason, I can get it to click a button with English text (between the  tags) but it does not work when the text is in Hebrew.
for the example, I was checking it out with Google(.co.il).

When I tried clicking the Gmail button on top, it worked. but when I tried clicking on "תמונות" which stands for photos in Hebrew, it occurred an error, and even the exception error couldn't be written (UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 86-91: ordinal not in range(128)).

## Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\User-PC\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.google.co.il/")
linkslist = [u'תמונות']
try:
    button = driver.find_element_by_link_text(linkslist[0])
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    button.click()
    print(driver.current_url)
except Exception as er:
    print "Error: ", format(er)
driver.close
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
driver.get('http://www.google.co.il/')
driver.find_element_by_link_text('תמונות').click()
```

Comment: Does not work for me. gives me an error:Traceback (most recent call last), it says:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('╫¬╫₧╫ץ╫á╫ץ╫¬').click()


and a couple of other lines I have no place to paste here.

Comment: there is a syntax error driver.close .......... its driver.close() as its a method on the driver. I didnt point it out assuming its copy paste error, can you confirm from your end?

Comment: check your print statement under the exception. I copied your code, fixed the 2 syntax issue and it works. Im using python 3.6, so print is a method

Comment: I have fixed the driver.close(), my bad. but I don't think it even occured an issue since it worked perfcetly when I picked the english label. You have mentioned that there were 2 syntax issues, which issue was the second one?
B.t.w I'm using Python 2.7 but I don't see a reason for it to not work only when switching to an hebrew title.

Answer (score 0):

There were a minor issue in your code block. The print statement was not proper. Here is the working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.google.co.il/")
linkslist = [u'תמונות']
try:
    button = driver.find_element_by_link_text(linkslist[0])
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    button.click()
    print(driver.current_url)
except Exception as er:
    print ("Error: ", format(er))
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

The output on my console is:

```
https://www.google.co.il/imghp?hl=iw&tab=wi
Process finished with exit code 0
```

### Update:

Now as per your update you are seeing an error as:

```
print ("Error: ", format(er)) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 86-91: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This pretty much expected as the IDE you are using may not be supporting **`Unicode`** characters. Hence we will only change the line for printing the exception only after converting the exception into readable **`utf-8`** character format as follows:

```
print ("Error: ", format(er)).encode('utf-8')
```

> or

```
print ("Error: ", format(er).encode('utf-8'))
```

Keep me updated with option suits you.

Comment: Running your script outputs: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check2.py", line 13, in <module>
    print ("Error: ", format(er))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 86-91: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: It didn't work. but when I used that line:
    print ("Error: ", format(unicode(er)))
it gave me a different error, 
('Error: ', u'Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"\u05ea\u05de\u05d5\u05e0\u05d5\u05ea"}\n  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.90)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)\n')

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to a solution,
I have used
    driver.find_element_by_link_text(linkslist[count]).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
instead of just driver.find_elements_by_link_text("texthere").click()

Thanks for all of the help, have a great week =)